# How to auto resize image to fit a container in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, image, containers, autoresize

I want two pictures to be one size - bootstrap col-6's size, when original images have different dimensions.

I tried this code:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"> 
      <div class="col-6">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502082553048-f009c37129b9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
          <h3><a href="#">project name</a></h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit aperiam esse sint quisquam. Obcaecati mollitia hic cum dolorum delectus vel laborum corrupti dolore possimus! Facere voluptatum aperiam maxime odit aut!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536431311719-398b6704d4cc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
          <h3><a href="#">project name</a></h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit aperiam esse sint quisquam. Obcaecati mollitia hic cum dolorum delectus vel laborum corrupti dolore possimus! Facere voluptatum aperiam maxime odit aut!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

But it did not work. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding width=100% to the img tag?

Another option would be adding a tag definition to col-6 class in your css file:
img.col-6{width:100%;}

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Please phrase the first part of this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: To the second part: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

you can readjust the image size by a simply adding style="width:400px;height:300px;" at the end of the image tag , you can change the pixels to your preferred size for each image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> </title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>


<body>


  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6"> <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502082553048-f009c37129b9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" style="width:400px;height:300px;"></div>


      <div class="col-6"> <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536431311719-398b6704d4cc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=300&q=40" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" style="width:400px;height:300px;"> </div>
    </div>


  </div>




  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <h3><a href="#">project name</a></h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit aperiam esse sint quisquam. Obcaecati mollitia hic cum dolorum delectus vel laborum corrupti dolore possimus! Facere voluptatum aperiam maxime odit aut!</p>
      </div>


      <div class="col-6">
        <h3><a href="#">project name</a></h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit aperiam esse sint quisquam. Obcaecati mollitia hic cum dolorum delectus vel laborum corrupti dolore possimus! Facere voluptatum aperiam maxime odit aut!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```